# Importing VCard file with ez-vcard library for Android

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, vcf-vcard

I'm trying to export all contacts data to a vcf file, using the ez-vcard library with the Android bridge (classes copied straight off of Github). I then want to restore the contacts from this file. So I manually delete a phone contact before restoring. However, it seems the deleted contact doesn't get restored. I can see that the contacts are correctly exported when examining the output vcf file so something seems to be wrong with the restore process.

There are no error messages. When importing the same file through Gmail, it works. But I need the import process to be done silently in a background thread, without any UI, so I can't do the importing through the Contacts app, which is why I've resorted to the ez-vcard library.

https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard

https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard-android

Exporting (error handling cut out for clarity):

```
public void exportContacts(Context context) {
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                writeContactToFile(context, c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }
}

private void writeContactToFile(Context context, Cursor c) {
    String lookupKey = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
    AssetFileDescriptor fd = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
    fis.read(buf);
    String vCard = new String(buf);
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE | Context.MODE_APPEND);
    fos.write(vCard.toString().getBytes());
}
```

Importing:

```
VCardReader reader = new VCardReader(file);
reader.registerScribe(new AndroidCustomFieldScribe());
ContactOperations operations = new ContactOperations(context);
VCard vCard;
while ((vCard = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    operations.insertContact(vCard);
}
```

Could it be some encoding issue or am I missing some pre-configurations of the library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are passing the correct `File` object into `VCardReader`?  If it can't find any vCards inside of the file, then the `insertContact` method will never be called because `reader.readNext()` will just return `null`.